# Rotating a symbolTriangle shape in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a triangle made here https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEzjE.jpg, and would like to rotate it 180 degrees so it it supside down. What is the process for this?

```
var sym6 =  d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolTriangle).size(500); 
    d3.select("#mysvg6") 
        .append("path") 
        .attr("d", sym6) 
        .attr("fill", "#2AE7D1") 
        .attr("transform", "translate(760, 310)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sym6 =  d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolTriangle).size(500); 
d3.select("#mysvg6") 
    .append("path") 
    .attr("d", sym6) 
    .attr("fill", "#2AE7D1") 
    .attr("transform", 'translate(760, 310) rotate(180)');
```